# Integrating smartgwt and web2py

Tags: django, web2py, smartgwt

I'd like to build an application using [smartgwt](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/) and [web2py](http://mdp.cti.depaul.edu/).
I am new to both.

Ultimately what I would like to do is display objects obtained from a web2py backend in a smartgwt TileGrid.

Can anyone enumerate the broad strokes of what needs to be done? Or point me to any useful resources?

Any information that would apply more to [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) is also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

download smartgwt (excellent framework by the way)  and look into this example:

file://localhost/Users/massimodipierro/Desktop/smartgwt-1.0b1/samples/Showcase/www/com.smartgwt.sample.showcase.Showcase/index.html#tiling_load_on_deamnd

which displays images in a tilegrid. The images are received from Yahoo via an http request. The response is in JSON. Look into the source code.   To  see the json response from Yahoo try the following URL:

http://api.search.yahoo.com/ImageSearchService/V1/imageSearch?appid=YahooDemo&output=json&query=snowboard

To make this work with web2py you need to replace that URL with the URL of a web2py action that returns a similar JSON response.

I do not know much about smartgwt but I am sure on the web2py google groups there are people willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.web2py.com/AlterEgo/default/show/203) on using web2py with Pajamas, which is another library built on GWT.